# Can i run apps from eclipse through adb on stock galaxy s3?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I've always been able to use adbWireless and launch my apps on my galaxy s3, but always on an aosp based ROM. Is it possible to do when on a stock based rom based on samsungs touchwiz? When ever I try to run my apps I get

Installation failed due to invalid apk file!
Please check log cat for more details.

In log cat I see:
Failed to parse package
Unable to open zip app.apk: permission denied

Then at error level I see "failed to init atd"

From what I've learned on google it sounds this is a problem on some ROMs. Which makes sense because I never have issues on aosp based ROMs. Is it possible to run apps through eclipse on touchwiz roms?

Comment: Where is the app.apk located?

Comment: Whatever the default location eclipse puts it in I think like data/tmp/app or something like that. I'll edit this comment when I get back to my PC to check.

Answer (score 0):

ADB Wireless only works if your phone is rooted -- have you rooted your GS3? If not, that's why it won't work.

You can still debug using standard ADB over USB.

Comment: Yes my gs3 is rooted. AdbWireless has no problems requesting root.